# Можно ли класс унаследовать от двух других классов

Tags: c#, unity3d

У меня есть проект в Unity, а в нём скрипт на c#. Я хочу унаследовать от `Monobehavior` и `Editor` одновременно.

Возможно ли это?

Comment: Множественное наследование от классов в с# не разрешено. Можно только производить наследование от одного класса и/или нескольких интерфейсов. При чем имя родительского класса должно быть на первом месте, до перечисления интерфейсов.

Comment: @Ivan переоформь в полноценный ответ, пожалуста. Твой коментарий полностью отвечает на поставленный вопрос

Comment: @Ivan, вы можете оформить как ответ. Вы ответили на мой вопрос.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Множественное наследование от классов в с# не разрешено. Можно только производить наследование от одного класса и/или нескольких интерфейсов. Причем имя родительского класса должно быть на первом месте, до перечисления интерфейсов.

Answer (score 2):

`MonoBehiavour` - это скрипт поведения для объекта в сцене.

`Editor` - это окно редактора в Unity.

Скрипты относятся к разным проектам, и в Game вам не доступны объекты редактора. Объясните толком что вы хотите сделать? Если для MonoBehaivour вы хотите сделать свое окно для редактирования параметров скрипта, то вам надо смотреть в сторону [расширений редактора](https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/current/Manual/ExtendingTheEditor.html). Это будет некая надстройка над редактором, которая при работе с вашим скриптом будет подстраивать редактор под ваши нужды.

Я бы использовал `PropertyDrawer`, их потом проще переиспользовать в других местах.

Если же вы хотите из игры управлять редактором: то это скорей всего говорит о неправильной архитектуре вашей задумки. Надо помнить, что собранное приложение не имеет редактора.

Answer (score 0):

Можно производить каскадное наследование 
Class one : MonoBehever
Class two : one
Class three : two

Третий будет содержать в себе все выше указанные функции и соответственно будет относиться к mono ,и его можно будет расположить на объекте